Cut function in R is not creating the desired number of intervals
My range of values is pretty tight but I want the cut function to force the intervals, even if it means making the interval range quite narrow. But it is not doing this.
temp <- c(8.32, 8.43, 8.41, 7.86, 7.98, 7.86, 8.07, 8.51, 7.92, 7.94, 8.36)
bins = 3
labels = c("Low","Medium","High")

categories <- cut(temp, breaks=bins, labels=labels)

> categories
 [1] High High High Low  Low  Low  Low  High Low  Low  High
Levels: Low Medium High

But if I ask it to cut into 4 intervals, I do get more of a range:
bins = 4
labels = c("Low","Medium","High", "Very High")

categories <- cut(temp, breaks=bins, labels=labels)

> categories
 [1] High      Very High Very High Low       Low       Low       Medium    Very High Low       Low       Very High
Levels: Low Medium High Very High

How can I get my 3 interval range to include some values as "medium"?

You should provide the desired break points instead of having ‘cut’ calculate them. Have you read ‘help(“cut”)’?

If you want to automate this and not specify the break points, ggplot2 has nice functions for this: cut_interval() makes n groups with equal range, cut_number() makes n groups with (approximately) equal numbers of observations; cut_width() makes groups of width width. See the docs .

There are no temp elements in the interval 8.076667 8.293333. That's why there are no `Medium values.

1) quantile Try cutting on quantiles
bins <- length(labels)
cut(temp, breaks = quantile(temp, 0:bins / bins), labels = labels,
  include.lowest = TRUE)


##  [1] Medium High   High   Low    Medium Low    Medium High   Low    Low   
## [11] High  
## Levels: Low Medium High

2) quantcut or try quantcut from gtools
library(gtools)
quantcut(temp, q = length(labels), labels = labels)

##  [1] Medium High   High   Low    Medium Low    Medium High   Low    Low   
## [11] High  
## Levels: Low Medium High


This worked great. Thanks!

Is there a way to see how quantcut is splitting up the data according to the number of bins I want? Just so I can see the range for each interval?

Before running quantcut run trace(quantcut, exit = quote(print(quant)))

or run quantcut(temp, q = 3)
